# Understanding Android TV activity lifecycle

Tags: java, android-lifecycle, android-tv

It has been a couple of months since I started to develop for android TV, I have an app fully working which displays two channels (Live and OnDemand) and some programs in the home screen:

[image]

I started the project using:
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tv-recommendations

which is DEPRECATED but it is the only working example I could find on the entire web (better than nothing).

My problem at the moment is that I'm not sure how to deal with the lifecycle of my `Activity` that manage the `Intent`s generated by the home screen itself.

I will try to describe it with an example:

Starting from the app completely closed I click on `OnDemand3` `Program`, here is the lifecycle observed:

```
Create -> Start -> Resume -> DO STUFF
```

Once that I press home on the remote the lifecycle terminates correctly:

```
DO STUFF -> Pause -> Stop [-> Destroy (not guaranteed)]
```

A this point the app stays in the background (doesn't get destroyed immediately). Everything seem fine and I can watch another `Program` pressing on the desired one (for example `OnDemand2`). Everything works as expected an the lifecycle is:

```
Create -> Start -> Resume -> DO STUFF -> Pause -> Stop
```

I can play any other `Program` and it will work as expected but there is an exception: if at some point later I play again the program that created the activity the first time (in the example `OnDemand3`) the lifecycle changes:

```
Restart -> Start -> Resume -> DO STUFF -> Pause -> Stop
```

The problem is that my `Activity` decide what video to play based on the `Intent` passed from the home screen, the fact is that when the `Activity` goes through `Restart` the `Intent` is not updated to the one of `OnDemand3`, rather, the `Intent` of the second last played Program is used!

I tried many workaround but the problem is that you get a `Restart` either with pressing on the first `Program` that created the `Activity` or with the press of the standby button. I haven't find any way to discriminate between the two `Restart`s and at this point I don't think there is a way.

Using the DEPRECATED project from google I can observe the same behavior which means that probably something has changed, but I really can't find a solution to this rather weird lifecycle.

Could anyone at least try to point me in the correct direction?

P.S. sorry If I haven't posted any code but I have a lot of it and the important part is scattered around the files, since the problem is present as well in https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tv-recommendations you could give a look there

Comment: I found a workaround: to discriminate the events you need to override `onUserLeaveHint`, this function gets called only when home button is pressed, standby event doesn't trigger it